# Ruby Gosu, my script gets and error with keyword end

Tags: ruby, syntax

The error is:

C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/MyFirstSelfMadeGame.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end

---

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "gosu"

class GameWindow < Gosu::Window

  def initialize(800, 600, false) #Window declaration
    super
    self.caption("Pokemon")
  end
  def update

  end
  def draw

  end
  def button_down(id)
    close if id == Gosu::KbSpace 
  end


end

GameWindow.new.show
```

Thanks for answers, i get this problem alot.

Comment: Please post the full error message, I don't think it starts with `rb`. Your code looks fine. Maybe the error comes from another file.

Comment: @pts Its the only file ive made for now, but the whole error is: C:/Users/Admin/Desktop/MyFirstSelfMadeGame.rb:18: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end

Comment: This is still not the whole error, please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pts says, you cannot reference objects in a method definition arguments

The method definition arguments should only contain variables that you reference in the method.

If you want to use defaults but have the option to override the arguments when calling the 'new' method you could do...

```
def initialize(width=800, height=600, full_screen=false)
  super(width, height, full_screen)
```

Also, you should note that `self.caption` is a getter method and doesn't take arguments

this is wrong

```
self.caption("Pokemon") # < wrong
```

this is right

```
self.caption = "Pokemon" # < right
```

Take a look at the tutorial game...

https://github.com/jlnr/gosu/wiki/Ruby-Tutorial

Comment: The Caption was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not the whole error, the whole error looks something like:

```
t.rb:6: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting ')'
  def initialize(800, 600, false) #Window declaration
                    ^
t.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end
```

Please note that there are 2 error messages reported by the Ruby interpreter. You have noticed and posted only the 2nd one, but the 1st one is actually the relevant one. In general, if you receive error messages, it's a good rule of thumb to find and fix the 1st one first, because the subsequent ones may be caused by the first one.

You need to specify for function arguments. Incorrect:

```
def initialize(800, 600, false) #Window declaration
```

Correct:

```
def initialize()
  super(800, 600, false)
```